# How to display the list of videos in two categories 1.'currentUser' videos and 2. 'otherUsers' videos within same class in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

The below code gives "otherUsers" videos

```
class Test(ListView):
    model = VideoUpload
    template_name = 'videoTube.html'
```

The below code gives "currentUser" videos

```
class Test(ListView):
    model = VideoUpload
    template_name = 'videoTube.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return VideoUpload.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

In templates

```
{% for vid in object_list %}
  {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}
    {{ vid.video }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My requirement is to display the list of videos in two categories
`1.List of 'currentUser' videos`
and
`2.List of 'otherUsers' videos`
within same class 'Test' which should display on the same html page

Comment: override get_context_data(self, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define method

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  context["other_video_list"] = VideoUpload.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user)
  return context
```

and then in your template you can use

```
{% for other_vid in other_video_list %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you @Maslov Andrey